# Is there any way to change background color and border margins of grid items in react-grid-layout library

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I've been implementing and looking to make a dynamic dashboard using react-grid-layout library and read the docs for the same but I'm unable to change the background and the text color of the grid item. Here's my code

```
import React from "react";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";
import "../../node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "../../node_modules/react-resizable/css/styles.css";
const Layout = () => {
  const layout = [
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, static: true },
    { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2, minW: 2, maxW: 4 },
    { i: "c", x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 },
  ];
  return (
    <GridLayout
      className="layout"
      layout={layout}
      cols={12}
      rowHeight={30}
      width={1200}
    >
      <div key="a">a</div>
      <div key="b">b</div>
      <div key="c">c</div>
    </GridLayout>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

```
Changes i made in css at
```

node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css

```
are 


`.react-grid-item {
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  background-color: brown;
  color: black;
  transition-property: left, top;
}
`
```

The result still stays the same:- [image: Output]

Any help with respect to changing the color of the items will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i see your code is working as expected , I just tried same exact thing here just check once https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-architecture-sk6v2m, I was able to see changes for item background as well as text color

Comment: Unable to see the code and output on the link you've mentioned

Comment: here is updated link https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstackoverflow01-0les26?file=/src/App.js let me this works